# Validating URL by making request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, url, request

In Rails controller, I'd like to validate a user-inputted URL (say, it's in a variable `url`) by making a request to it, and checking that the response is not 50X. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send request from a controller using `Net::Http` module as follows

```
uri = URI('http://festivalsherpa.com')
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
```

---

```
response.to_hash["status"] will return you proper response code
```

Comment: I see. And now that I've read the doc, I realize that `response.code` will be the return code. Is it a good idea to check that the response does not begin with `50`?

Comment: Is `response.to_hash["status"]` different from `response.code`, or are they the same?

Comment: I don't know. But when i tried response.to_hash["status"] returned "200" i.e just response code

Answer (score 0):

### There is one more way

you can do in more meaningful way like:

```
uri = URI.parse(your_url)
connection = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri) # For post req, you can replace 'Get' by  'Post'
response = connection.request(request)
```

You can see what is returned:

```
p response.body
```

If the response returned is JSON, then you can do

```
JSON.parse(response.body)  #It will give you hash object
```

You can check the response code/status

```
  p response.code
```

If you want to handle status codes, then you can handle it through case statements

```
case response.code
 when "200"
     <some code>
 when "500"
     <some code>
 end
```

And so on..